# How can OpenMP know how many loop instances are nested?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, openmp

I used OpenMP from a long time ago in writing c++ program.
Suddnely, a question comes in to my mind.

"How can OpenMP know how many loop instances are nested?"

Is it explicitly counted by compiler?

Comment: `#pragma omp for collapse(n)`, see the [specification](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **OpenMP runtime** keeps track of this information in thread-local variables.

Probably one of the most popular OpenMP implementations out there, `libgomp`, is open-source; That means one can read not just its documentation but also its source code entirely free.

The implementation of `omp_get_level()` is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libgomp/parallel.c?view=markup#l259):

```
int
omp_get_level (void)
{
  return gomp_thread ()->ts.level;
}
```

The implementation of `gomp_thread()` is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libgomp/libgomp.h?view=markup#l649). It retrieves a pointer to a thread-local structure.

```
#if defined __nvptx__
extern struct gomp_thread *nvptx_thrs __attribute__((shared));
static inline struct gomp_thread *gomp_thread (void)
{
  int tid;
  asm ("mov.u32 %0, %%tid.y;" : "=r" (tid));
  return nvptx_thrs + tid;
}
#elif defined HAVE_TLS || defined USE_EMUTLS
extern __thread struct gomp_thread gomp_tls_data;
static inline struct gomp_thread *gomp_thread (void)
{
  return &gomp_tls_data;
}
#else
extern pthread_key_t gomp_tls_key;
static inline struct gomp_thread *gomp_thread (void)
{
  return pthread_getspecific (gomp_tls_key);
}
#endif
```

The data structure `ts` is a `struct gomp_team_state` that, amongst others, [contains](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libgomp/libgomp.h?view=markup#l308):

```
  [...]
  /* Nesting level.  */
  unsigned level;

  /* Active nesting level.  Only active parallel regions are counted.  */
  unsigned active_level;
  [...]
```

And whenever `#pragma omp parallel` is used, the compiler extracts the body of the parallel section into a subfunction and generates a complicated set of function calls that eventually lead to `gomp_team_start()`, which [contains](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libgomp/team.c?view=markup#l331):

```
#ifdef LIBGOMP_USE_PTHREADS
void
gomp_team_start (void (*fn) (void *), void *data, unsigned nthreads,
                 unsigned flags, struct gomp_team *team)
{

  [...]

  ++thr->ts.level;
  if (nthreads > 1)
    ++thr->ts.active_level;
```

Comment: thanks! so this is how openmp runtime library keeps track the active level of nesting. Surely, the pre-compiler for openmp know how many loops are nested when it constructs the compicated function calls leading to gomp_teat_start().

In summary, active_level is counted at run-time. Statically, the openmp pre-compiler perform analysis on the loops and can find the loop counts

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as it relates to nesting of parallel regions and not loops, unless the question is badly posed.

Comment: @HristoIliev My interpretation of the question was that "nesting level" couldn't refer to C-language `for`-loop levels, either global (callstack) or local (within single function). The C language doesn't track it globally. The compiler has trivial access to the local nesting level within a function, but so does the programmer. So this had to be a global, OpenMP concept, and the only similar concept in OpenMP is the return value of `omp_get{_active}_level()`. I did point out it counts `#pragma omp parallel` levels, but `parallel` is frequently (but not always!) associated with `for` instances.